# connect with tramp, sudo and edit a file as root in GCP

Tags: tramp, ssh, systemd, google-cloud-compute, tramp-methods

I have a virtual machine in **Google Cloud Compute** where I can ssh/login as my own user, and then `sudo` to root in order to access files used by a **systemd** service. I would like to edit these files through **tramp**. How can I achieve this?

Current tramp method to connect as my own user:

```lisp
;; make sure you've set your default project with:
;; gcloud config set project <project-name>

(require 'tramp)
(add-to-list
 'tramp-methods
 '("gcssh"
   (tramp-login-program "gcloud compute ssh")
   (tramp-login-args (("%h")))
   (tramp-async-args (("-q")))
   (tramp-remote-shell "/bin/sh")
   (tramp-remote-shell-args ("-c"))
   (tramp-gw-args (("-o" "GlobalKnownHostsFile=/dev/null")
                   ("-o" "UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null")
                   ("-o" "StrictHostKeyChecking=no")))
   (tramp-default-port 22)))

;; ... after which it's as easy as:
;;
;; C-x C-f /gcssh:compute-instance:/path/to/filename.smile
```

[source](https://gist.github.com/jackrusher/36c80a2fd6a8fe8ddf46bc7e408ae1f9)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’ve already given one possible answer, but there is no need to create a special tramp method for root access; there are generic su and sudo methods, and you can chain multiple methods together into a single path.

So if `/gcssh:compute-instance:/etc/systemd/system/foo.service` opens the systemd unit file that you care about on the host `compute-instance`, then `/gcssh:compute-instance|sudo::/etc/systemd/system/foo.service` will sudo to root first, before opening the file.

Edit:

TRAMP has it’s own manual, but it does come with Emacs. Use `C-h i` to open the Info browser, and select the TRAMP manual from the list. You might start with [chapter 4.1 File name syntax](https://www.gnu.org/software/tramp/#File-name-syntax-1). Each TRAMP filename is three parts — the method, “remote” hostname, and path — separated by colons. For ssh, you can specify a username, host, and port as part of the hostname, so `/ssh:bob@example.com#2222:/path/to/file`. The `sudo` method also lets you specify a user name; it assumes you mean root if it is left out. Weirdly you can also give it a host name, and it will ssh there first. `/sudo::/path/to/file` is the same as `/sudo:root@localhost:/path/to/file`.

Comment: I was trying a permutation of that, but couldn't get it right. What's the `::` for, and where can I learn about it in the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

The trick was to add all connect commands to the list in `tramp-login-args`. So

```
gcloud compute ssh test -- sudo su
```

became

```lisp
(add-to-list
 'tramp-methods
 '("gcsroot"
   (tramp-login-program "gcloud compute ssh")
   (tramp-login-args (("%h" "--" "sudo" "su")))
   (tramp-async-args (("-q")))
   (tramp-remote-shell "/bin/sh")
   (tramp-remote-shell-args ("-c"))
   (tramp-gw-args (("-o" "GlobalKnownHostsFile=/dev/null")
                   ("-o" "UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null")
                   ("-o" "StrictHostKeyChecking=no")))
   (tramp-default-port 22)))
```